# Go to page URL using test.BeforeAll for playwright-test runner

Tags: javascript, playwright

```
test.beforeAll(async ({ page }) => {
   // Go to the starting url before each test.
   await page.goto('https://my.start.url/');
 });
```

Is there a nice way in playwright-test runner to setup the browser and navigate to the page related to the page object to run the tests in that file?

I want to avoid doing this "test.beforeEach" for everyone if possible. Currently its not possible to do this in playwright-test but it is possible in jest. Any ideas?

```
Property 'page' does not exist on type 'PlaywrightWorkerArgs & PlaywrightWorkerOptions'.
```

Answer (score 13):

As said above (by Leon), you can create your own page, but to avoid creating a new page for each test (Joaquin Casco asked about it), just don't pass page as a parameter to your test function.

I mean:

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');

test.beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Go to the starting url before each test.
    await page.goto('https://my.start.url/');
});

// Will create a new page instance
test('Test with page as parameter', async ({ page }) => {}) 

// Does not create new page, so you can use the page from beforeAll hook (if you bring it into the scope)
test('Test without page as parameter', async () => {})
```

Comment: would this prevent you from running tests outside of chromium?

Comment: How do you bring into the scope of the second test?

Answer (score 7):

```
// example.spec.ts

import { test, Page } from '@playwright/test';

test.describe.configure({ mode: 'serial' });

let page: Page;

test.beforeAll(async ({ browser }) => {
  // Create page once and sign in.
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://github.com/login');
  await page.locator('input[name="user"]').fill('user');
  await page.locator('input[name="password"]').fill('password');
  await page.locator('text=Sign in').click();
});

test.afterAll(async () => {
  await page.close();
});

test('first test', async () => {
  // page is signed in.
});

test('second test', async () => {
  // page is signed in.
});
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-auth#reuse-the-signed-in-page-in-multiple-tests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137125/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

You could create a `page` by yourself:

```js
const { chromium } = require('playwright');
const { test } = require('@playwright/test');

test.beforeAll(async () => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Go to the starting url before each test.
    await page.goto('https://my.start.url/');
});
```

You need install the `playwright` package.

Comment: `const { chromium } = require('@playwright/test');`

works as well

Comment: this will restart the chromium instance after the `beforeAll` finishes, is there a way to keep the browser open until I say so?